# Why multiple instances on single server is better than single intance on single server?

Tags: linux, load-balancing, java, cluster

Want to understand why cluster with multiple instances on single server is better than single instance on single server.

Assuming linux server with 16GB RAM and for java application.

Answer (score 1):

It is not easy to answer such a question unless more details are provided.

You may gain some performance if you run multiple instances of your application, but this depends on your application and what it is doing.

For example, if your application is making good use of server resources, you may not benefit at all. You may even get worse performance when these instances compete for shared resources!

When optimizing performance you need first to find out where the bottleneck is and try to eliminate by one or more of the following:

- Adding more resources / more servers.
- Running more instances.
- Optimizing some operations in the application itself.
- Optimizing load-balancer itself.
- ....